# Loop through subfiles and move files with whitespaces

Tags: windows, cmd

this might seems trivial but I'm used to work with Linux and I can't get this simple loop to work correctly on Windows Server.

Basically : I have a tree of folders, I have to go through all the subfolders and move every file I find to a completely different folder.

Here is what I type when I'm the the parent folder (I tried to implement delims here and there but can"t get it to work properly)

```
for /R %a in (*.*) do move %a e:/final/folder
```

Basically it works with every file but the ones with white spaces in it. (It also bugs if a subfolder has a whitespace so I filled them with underscore...)

Regards

Comment: It was that simple... I'm ashamed haha. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /R %a in (*.*) do move "%a" e:\final\folder
```

"quoting a path or filename" treats the contents of the quotes as a single string (space, comma, semicolon, tab, `=` are separators)

Use backslash for directory-separators. Forward slashes are used for switches. The conversion is inconsistent.

Comment: It was that simple... I'm ashamed haha. Thanks a lot